# Windows can't wake up after an upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep

I am using Windows 10. I always leave my PC on sleep when I am not around and wake it up by pressing any key. This has worked fine until 1803, but in every subsequent Windows update after I put my computer to sleep and wake it up, the screen stays black. I can hear all the fans working and all the peripherals light up, but the screen stays in sleep mode.

Now I have been forced to upgrade to the latest update and I still have this issue. I thought that maybe it was because of the motherboard so I updated Bios. I have ASRock 870 Extreme3 R2.0

What could be the possible reason? Where should I start looking?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has many causes. Below are listed some of them with suggestions.

- Run the Power troubleshooter
- Restore Power Plan Default Settings : In Power Options, click Change plan settings,
  then "Restore default settings for this plan"
- Turn of Hibernation using a Command Prompt (cmd) run as Administrator:

  ```
  powercfg /h off
  ```
- Update graphics card driver (download only from the manufacturer)
- Update BIOS (very carefully, download only from the computer/motherboard manufacturer)
- Search the BIOS for a function called "BIOS PSP Support" (if exists in your BIOS)
  and enable it
- A claimed
  [solution](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-sleepwake-issue-black-screen/b1fc4107-3cc8-4d0d-9807-acf9e84e4e80)
  was to use `regedit` to navigate to the key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration`,
  where the resolution is entered wrongly in six entries that need to
  be corrected. Reboot is recommended, as well as creating a System Restore point
  before modifying the registry.

Comment: Although disabling *hibernation* certainly has a couple of benefits and I always do it on my own PC, I'm pretty sure it wouldn't solve a problem with resuming from *sleep*.